# SAP Management Reporting

Tags: crystal-reports, report

I'm an ICT & Business student, currently doing an internship in a quite big company. My assignment is to find a way to deliver Management Reports to Line Managers.

The company is using SAP (Employee data such as name, department, contract start-end date etc. can be found there).

The managers don’t have SAP accounts therefore they can’t login to SAP. I need to find a way to retrieve the data from SAP, create custom reports and deliver them to the managers (via mail or website where the reports will be stored).

Can Crystal Reports do that? Or do I need additional tools?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know in order to send reports to recipients you need to have BO license for each recipient. 
Cheaper (even free) alternative will be to use one of the 3rd party tools available on the market. Groff Automation (http://www.groffautomation.com/) has a free scheduler, which can be used to run and send reports by e-mail. It is pretty basic , but will do the job. 
Another free option is the free license from R-Tag ([www.r-tag.com](http://www.r-tag.com)), free license is available from this link: http://www.r-tag.com/Pages/FreeCrystalReportsViewer.aspx
This one has more options , but the free license is just for the viewer. If you want to schedule the reports you need to purchase their scheduler license.

If you are willing to purchase a license for a scheduler you can check also the other available options from this link:
http://kenhamady.com/cru/comparisons/desktop-scheduling-engines

It contains the 2 products mentioned above + some more.